# Craft CMS 3 GetQueryParam Query parameter always coming back as null from user input

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, craftcms

Implementing a search bar in craft cms 3 application and query is always returning null from user input. Entries are always fetched correctly, searchTerm as shown in the code is always null. NO errors in the console or network tab.

[image: SearchController.php]

[image: search_bar.twig]

[image: custom module R.php]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)